# Can't resolve all parameters for RouterUtilities

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I want to create a RouterUtilities class that extends Angular's Router. The app works and compiles correctly but `ng build --prod` returns error such as:

```
ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for RouterUtilities in .../utils/router/router-utilities.ts: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object],
[object Object], ?).
```

router-utilities.ts

```
import { Compiler, Injectable, Injector, NgModuleFactoryLoader, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, UrlSerializer, ChildrenOutletContexts, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { formatPattern } from 'url-matcher';

import { Dictionary } from '../../../shared/interfaces/common.interface';

@Injectable()
export class RouterUtilities extends Router {
  constructor(rootComponentType: Type<any> | null,
              urlSerializer: UrlSerializer,
              rootContexts: ChildrenOutletContexts,
              location: Location,
              injector: Injector,
              loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
              compiler: Compiler,
              config: Routes) {
    super(rootComponentType, urlSerializer, rootContexts, location, injector, loader, compiler, config);
  }

  static getAbsoluteRoute(routePath: string, params: Dictionary<string> = {}): string {
    return 'something';
  }
}
```

Have you any idea why does it happen?

1. I've included this RouterUtilities in module's providers.
2. I didn't injected this service in any component/service yet.
3. The error is being returned even if this service hasn't been used.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference when you use `--prod` build. `Compiler` is only available in Just-in-Time (JIT) compilation and `--prod` switch enables Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation. So when angular tries to compile your service into factory it cannot find the `Compiler` dependency.

Maybe this [long github discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20875) will help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include the Router in deps like:

`providers: [
  {
    provide: RouterUtilities,
    useClass: RouterUtilities,
    deps: [Router]
  }
]`